# Load html file in typescript

Tags: javascript, angularjs, typescript

I have an html file in the same directory of the typescript file. IO have to load it and return it from the function.

```
public ...(... ) :  angular.IHttpPromise<string> {
   ...
   return $http({
            method: 'GET',
            url: 'help.html'
   });
```

Error: NetworkError: 404 Not Found - http://localhost:3000/help.html

Comment: What is unclear about a 404 error? The URL is wrong.

Comment: How can I fix it? My resource is local, I don't have an URL

Comment: Either (1) Work out what URL that file actually has or (2) Look at the server side to figure out how to make the file have the URL you are requesting. Either way, nothing about your client side code tells us anything about why the server can't find what you are asking for.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The directory does not matter. Why?

- The typescript file is actually javascript and this runs on the browser ie. the client's machine and not your server. The client has no clue what the structure is on the server so placing these files in the same folder is a convenience for the developer and nothing more.
- The `HTM` / `HTML` file is hosted on your server and the server knows nothing about the client.

To fix it - You have to specify the path to your html file in the `$http` command so the server knows where to pick it up from. The path always starts at the root of the folder that is hosted by IIS (or appache or whatever). So if you are hosting it in a folder named `someFolder` in the root of the web site folder then your url that you would use in the typescript file would be `/someFolder/help.html`.

If you want to manually test that the url is correct you should be able to put it directly in the URL of your web browser (along with the host) and it should return the content.